# Sharing private JIRA filters

Tags: jira

Until 2018 it was straightforward to create a JIRA filter and share it.

Create Filter
Edit Filter Details
Share with either a group or an individual

This option has now gone from the Filter Edit details dialogue and there seems nowhere one can share a private filter. The only available information details how to change the owner of an already SHARED filter.

Absolutely atrocious upgrade by Atlassian. I need to share dashboards but can't until I can share a filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this:
Click on the search icon at the left bar and find the filter you want to share. Then click on the second icon at the right top.

[image]

Additional note: For enabling Filter permission to group share, We can click on the "Details" link on top of the filter's page and then click on "Edit permissions" link within popup for viewing the shares drop down field with options. Steps are given below.

1. Click on "Details" link.
2. Click on "Edit permissions" link on popup.
3. "Edit Current Filter" popup will appear. In that Shares dropdown with options(Group, Project, Any logged-in user, Public) are available. Choose the relevant options and then click "+Add" button.
4. Click the "Save" button.

For sharing a dashboard, it's enough to click on the ellipsis icon at the right top of the page and find the share dashboard option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, which turned out it was my ad blocker removing share option from the Jira page. Exclude your Jira URL from the adblocker and reload the page.